# YDN DB Delete record by ID (IndexedDB)

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, ydn-db

I am using YDN DB for IndexedDB and I want to delete a record from the object store using its id.
Here is my schema:

```
var personsSchema = {
name: "persons",
keyPath: "id",
autoIncrement: true,
indexes: [{
    name: "id",
    unique: true
}, {
    name: "firstname",
    unique: false,
    multiEntry: false
}, {
    name: "lastname",
    unique: false,
    multiEntry: false
}]
};

schema = {
    stores: [personsSchema]
};

var db = new ydn.db.Storage("xdb", schema);
```

Now, I have function that will delete the record:

```
    function deleteEntry(id){
        var id = parseInt(id);
        var objectStore = "persons";
        var iterator = new ydn.db.ValueCursors(objectStore, "id", ydn.db.KeyRange.only(id));
        var mode = "readwrite";
        request = db.open(iterator, 1).then(function(cursor){
            cursor.clear();
        }, mode);
    }
```

This function gives me this error:

`Uncaught ydn.error.ArgumentException: Second argument must be cursor range iterator.`

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
function deleteEntry(id){
    var id = parseInt(id);
    var objectStore = "persons";
    var iterator = new ydn.db.IndexValueCursors(objectStore, "id", ydn.db.KeyRange.only(id));
    var mode = "readwrite";
    request = db.open(function(cursor){
        cursor.clear();
    }, iterator, mode).then(function() {
        console.log('cleared')
    });
}
```

But since `id` is primary key, you don't need to be indexed, it should simply be:

```
function deleteEntry(id){
    var id = parseInt(id, 10);
    var keys = db.remove("persons", id);
}
```

If id is not primary key, this following code run a bit more efficient, since it does not retrieve record values, unnecessarily.

```
function deleteEntry(id){
    var id = parseInt(id);
    var objectStore = "persons";
    db.keys(objectStore, "id", ydn.db.KeyRange.only(id)).done(function(keys) { 
      db.remove(objectStore, keys);
    };
}
```

I have corrected the [api doc example](http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html#open).

Comment: this give me an error: Uncaught TypeError: reverse . BTW, thanks for this plugin.

Comment: I used db.remove(). Thanks!

Comment: I get this error after I executed the function deleteEntry() from your first snippet in this answer

Comment: I see, it should be `IndexValueCursors`.